# If $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I know that if $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a PID, and I also know that if $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain then it a PID and therefore $F$ is a field. However, can we say that if $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain? If so, what would be a sketch of a proof? Otherwise, is there an easy example of $F[x]$ that is a PID but not Euclidean?

Comment: I thought the first proof everyone sees that $F[x]$ is a PID is by showing it is a Euclidean domain using the obvious division algorithm.

Comment: Do you know how to do the euclidean division in $\Bbb R[x]$ (or, say, $\Bbb Q[x],\,\Bbb C[x]$...)? Because it is exactly the same.

Comment: $F[x]$ is Euclidean with $d(f)={\rm deg}(f)$. This is usually explained in abstract algebra books dealing with Euclidean rings.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the norm $N(p(x)) = deg(p(x))$ (the degree of p(x)). To prove something is a Euclidean domain, you need to prove you can use the Euclidean algorithm $x=qy + r$ where $N(r) < N(x)$ (excluding edge cases where $x = 0$). Let $A$ and $B$ be any two polynomials in $F[x]$. Let's try to put the in the form $A = qB + r$. If $deg(B) > deg(A)$, then $r = A$ and we are done. Let $deg(A) \geq deg(B) = k$. Let $B(x) = cx^k + B'(x)$ where $c \in F$ and $B'(x)$ is all of the lower order terms of $B(x)$. Similarly, let $A(x) = dx^n + A'(x)$. Then since $F$ is a field, we can take $h(x) = \frac{d}{c}x^{n-k} \in F[x]$ and we can take $A(x) - h(x)*B(x) = A'(x) - h(x)*B'(x)$ which will be some polynomial of degree less than n. This process can then be repeated with new polynomials $h'(x)$ derived in the same manner until the degree of the remaining polynomial is less than k, and call this polynomial r. By taking all of the polynomials $h(x)$, $h'(x)$,... used in each step and adding them together, we have some polynomial q(x) such that $A = qB + r$.